# Why systemctl reload firewalld on centos7 is not working?

Tags: centos, firewalld

Running the following commands on CentOS7

```
#systemctl start firewalld
#systemctl enable firewalld
#systemctl reload firewalld
#systemctl status firewalld
```

gives output as follows:

```
...Active:inactive(dead) since...
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi down voter! Please add comment for down voting as It will help me to improve the question quality.

Comment: `reload` re-loads configuration files if service knows how to do that. Your service is dead, so you need to try to start it first. Read `man systemctl`. I too do not agree with downvoting, the crowd who believes they own this resource uses downvoting excessively.

Comment: Sorry! I did that but thought last 2 commands would be sufficient. Now, I edited the question

Comment: Check the status after each of those commands to see where exactly it dies.

Comment: do you have errors in `/var/log/messages` or other logs regarding the reload of the firewalld service?  You post the line `...Active:inactive(dead) since...`, the `since` part will tell you exactly when systemd saw that the service died.  If the time is before you ran `systemctl start firewalld`, then you have some errors preventing the service from starting.

Comment: Typically you would enable a service before starting it. You may have a conflict like the iptables service.
Reloading isn't necessary at start up, just start the service and then request status. 
A full journalctl output may be useful.